# Set up SIM7000E via PPP

Tags: ppp, gprs

I am trying to set up SIM7000E via ppp. SIM7000E is connected to a beaglebone black via micro USB cable. Beaglebone uses 5.10.168-ti-r71 kernel (Debian). SIM7000E drivers have been installed successfully and also ppp is installed too.

I entered the directory /etc/ppp/peers, copied the file provider and named it gprs. Gprs file looks like this:

```
example configuration for a dialup connection authenticated with PAP or CHAP

This is the default configuration used by pon(1) and poff(1).
See the manual page pppd(8) for information on all the options.
MUST CHANGE: replace myusername@realm with the PPP login name given to
your by your provider.
There should be a matching entry with the password in /etc/ppp/pap-secrets
and/or /etc/ppp/chap-secrets.

user "myusername@realm"

MUST CHANGE: replace ******** with the phone number of your provider.
The /etc/chatscripts/pap chat script may be modified to change the
modem initialization string.

connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs"

Serial device to which the modem is connected.

/dev/ttyUSB2

Speed of the serial line.

115200

nocrtscts

debug

nodetach

ipcp-accept-local

ipcp-accept-remote

Assumes that your IP address is allocated dynamically by the ISP.

noipdefault

Try to get the name server addresses from the ISP.

usepeerdns

Use this connection as the default route.

defaultroute

Makes pppd "dial again" when the connection is lost.

persist

Do not ask the remote to authenticate.

noauth
```

Then when I try to call gprs by typing: `pppd call gprs` The result is this:

```
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs finished (pid 1186), status = 0x0

Serial connection established.

using channel 2

Using interface ppp0

Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2

sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf0cd2f0e> ]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x4 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd0a7832b> ]

sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x4 ]

rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf0cd2f0e> ]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x5 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd0a7832b> ]

sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x5 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd0a7832b> ]

sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xf0cd2f0e]

sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="myusername@realm" password=]

rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x6 magic=0xd0a7832b]

rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xd0a7832b f0 cd 2f 0e]

rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]

PAP authentication succeeded

sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x7 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]

Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x1 magic=0xf0cd2f0e]

IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests

IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Requests

sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]

sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]

Connection terminated.

Modem hangup
```

I do not understand where is the problem. Can anyone help with this?